# Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

Tags: r, statistics, shiny

I am trying to select the cell in the DataTable and show the corresponding position/value.
But it seems not working... I ran the code from [the example cell code from Yihui](https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-selection/) but still showing the same error as I got from my code:

[Warning: Error in match.arg: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
Stack trace (innermost first):
    76: match.arg
    75: datatable
    74: widgetFunc
    73: func
    72: renderFunc
    71: output$x16
     4: 
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvaSI.png)

Below are part of my code.

biTableMatrix function - It assign the values to a certain position in the matrix/df by the xpos (row) and ypos (column). Firstly it returned a matrix, but I thought the error might be caused by the object type (matrix instead of data.frame from the example), so I convert it to data.frame - not much help thou...

```
# The following are in helper.R

travelMeans <- c('02', '04')
prepareTwoMeans <- function(travelMeans) {
  listx <- subset(geodata[geodata$MeanCode==travelMeans[1],], select = -c( AreaFull,MeanName,MeanFull))
  listx <- listx[order(listx$Percentage),] 

  listy <- subset(geodata[geodata$MeanCode==travelMeans[2],], select = -c( AreaFull,MeanName,MeanFull,AreaCode))
  listy <- listy[order(listy$Percentage),] 

  listx$xpos <- seq(length=nrow(listx))
  listy$ypos <- seq(length=nrow(listy))

  listx <- merge(listx, listy, by.x = c("AreaName"), by.y = c("AreaName"), all=TRUE)
  return(listx)  
}

# This function generates the two-way table of two travel means
biTableMatrix <- function(travelMeans) {
  fullList <- prepareTwoMeans(travelMeans)
  len <- length(fullList$AreaName)
  biTableMat <- matrix(data = "", nrow = len, ncol = len, dimnames = list(seq(length = len), seq(length = len)))#, 

  for (n in 1:len) {
    x <- fullList$xpos[n]
    y <- fullList$ypos[n]
    biTableMat[x,y] <- as.character(fullList$AreaName[n]) #fullList$AreaCode[n]
  }

  return(as.data.frame(biTableMat) )
}

# The following are in server.R
  biTable <- reactive({
    return(biTableMatrix(input$travelMeans))
  })

  output$biTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
     biTable()
     , selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell")
     , extensions = list("Scroller", "RowReorder")
     , options = list(
        scrollX = 500
      , scrollY = 700
      , rowReorder = FALSE
     )      
   )}
    , options = list(
      searchHighlight = TRUE
    )
  )

 output$biTableText <- renderPrint(input$biTable_cells_selected$value)
```

For reference, here is my ui.R

```
#Definte UI for the application
ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarPanel(
    # The following part is groupCheckBox format for the travelMeans
    checkboxGroupInput(
      "travelMeans"
      , label = "Select the mean below:"
      , choices = meanChoices
      , selected = NULL
    )

    , br()
  ),

  #Show the map
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(#type = "tabs",
        tabPanel("Single-Mean Table", DT::dataTableOutput("onetable"), hr())

      , tabPanel("Two-way table", DT::dataTableOutput("biTable"), hr(), verbatimTextOutput("biTableText"))
    )

    , position="center"
   , height= "auto"
  )
)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score -3):

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

Do not use the cran DT.

Comment: Sorry, I mean you could use the DT from github since it is the most developed version of DT. CRAN DT is slowly updated.